# Spring data neo4j 4 Date can't cast

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am using spring data neo4j 4. I stored object successfully. But when I retrieve object from neo4j, I am getting following exception:

Code:

```
@DateLong
private Date earliest;
@DateLong
private Date latest;
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.DateLongConverter.toEntityAttribute(DateLongConverter.java:22) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.entityaccess.FieldWriter.write(FieldWriter.java:64) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.writeProperty(GraphEntityMapper.java:164) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.setProperties(GraphEntityMapper.java:129) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:110) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
at 4j.ogm.mapper.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:94) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.2.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in neo4j-ogm 1.1.2, please use neo4j-ogm version 1.1.4